# Arduino serial monitor not showing anything

Tags: timer, arduino

I'm doing a code where the timer gets triggered by a pushbutton. The problem is that nothing happens, the serial monitor doesn't show anything. I've checked all of the connections and there is no errors in the electronic components. I'm not sure what is wrong.
Thankyou

Here's the code:

```
int timer;
const int starttrigger = 2;
const int endtrigger = 4;

void setup() {
  pinMode(starttrigger, INPUT);
  pinMode(endtrigger, INPUT);
  pinMode(redled, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenled, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int start_button_state = digitalRead(starttrigger);
  int end_button_state = digitalRead(endtrigger); 
  if (start_button_state == HIGH) {
    while (end_button_state == LOW){
      for(timer = 0; end_button_state == HIGH; timer ++) {
        Serial.println(timer);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `while (end_button_state == LOW){
      for(timer = 0; end_button_state == HIGH; timer ++)` that's a mess right there.

Comment: `Serial.begin` is missing

Answer (score -1):

You do not see anything in the serial monitor because you have not activating Serial communication in the first place. It needs to be done in the void setup() function.

Please add this line to your void setup function

`Serial.begin(9600);`